# Oracle 11g: IN equivalent for a String

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have 2 tables

**Table T1**

```
CODE | INDS  | A ..
-----+-------+----
10   | 1,2,3 | foo
11   | 1,2,3 | bar
```

**Table T2**

```
CODE | IND | X ..
-----+-----+------
10   | 1   |
10   | 2   |
10   | 3   |
11   | 1   |
11   | 2   |
11   | 3   |
```

I'm trying to write a SQL query that will join both tables for the same `CODE` and `IND`, such as `IND IN (INDS)`.

So something like:

```
SELECT T1.A, T2.X 
FROM T1, T2
WHERE  T1.CODE = T2.CODE 
AND    T2.IND IN (T1.INDS)
```

Which won't work as IN don't expect a String but comma separated values.

**Question**

How can this be made with a SQL query ?

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Thanks. But that's the table I have to deal with. Despite I couldn't say what's wrong having coma separated values (beside CSV ?)

Comment: It violates the basic design premise of data normalization called first normal form.

Comment: I have to deal with similar data structure at work. Sometimes you just have to deal with legacy code/data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `INSTR` function to search for the number in the comma separated values.

```
SELECT T1.A
,      T2.X
FROM   T1
,      T2
WHERE  T1.CODE = T2.CODE
AND    INSTR(T1.INDS, T2.IND) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a really, really bad data structure.  You should not be storing ids in a string.  Why not?

- Numbers should not be stored as strings.
- Ids should have properly declared foreign key relationships.
- SQL has lousy string processing capabilities.
- Your data structure impedes optimization.
- SQL has a great data type for storing lists.  It is called a table.  (And Oracle has other mechanisms as well.)

Sometimes we are stuck with other people's really, really, really bad design decisions.  In this case, you can use `like`, but pay attention to the delimiters:

```
SELECT T1.A, T2.X 
FROM T1 JOIN 
     T2
     ON T1.CODE = T2.CODE AND
         ',' || T1.INDS || ',' LIKE '%,' || T2.IND || ',%';
```

You can also phrase this using `regexp_like()`:

```
SELECT T1.A, T2.X 
FROM T1 JOIN 
     T2
     ON T1.CODE = T2.CODE AND
        REGEXP_LIKE(t2.IND, '^' || REPLACE(t1.INDS, ',', '|') + '$';
```

Comment: Thanks! I noticed you replaced the comma by a pipe character in your second query. Can you please explain the benefit of it ?

Comment: @HeyStackExchange . . . That is regular-expression-speak for "or".

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
SELECT a, x
FROM   t1, t2
WHERE  t1.code = t2.code
  and  regexp_like(inds,'(^|,)'||ind||'(,|$)')
```

[JS Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/776e0/2)